# Draggable implementation not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing around the implementation of draggable divs. The code is pretty straightforward. It seems to work with Chrome but things get wonky under Firefox and same is jsfiddle.

jsfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/LXUuh/

```
 var activeDiv, movingMode, originalTop, originalLeft, originalPageX, originalPageY;

  $(".draggable").mousedown(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    activeDiv = $(this);
    movingMode = true;
    originalTop = $(this).offset().top;
    originalLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    originalPageX = event.pageX;
    originalPageY = event.pageY;
  });

  $("body").mousemove(function(event) {
    if (activeDiv) {
      var top  = originalTop + event.pageY - originalPageY,
          left = originalLeft + event.pageX - originalPageX;
      // activeDiv.css({
      //   position: "absolute",
      //   top: top,
      //   left: left
      // });
      activeDiv.offset({
        left: left,
        top: top
      });
      originalTop = top;
      originalLeft = left;
      originalPageX = event.pageX;
      originalPageY = event.pageY;
    }
  });

  var unbindDraggble = function(event) {
    if (activeDiv) {
      activeDiv = null;
    }
  };

  $("body").mouseup(unbindDraggble);
  $(".draggable").focusout(unbindDraggble);
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [micro library](https://github.com/gtramontina/draggable.js) that does what you need?

Comment: Thanks. It is useful. But I am trying to write it myself so that I would learn how things works out.

Comment: I see your point. Please feel free to look at the source code of that lib to get some insights. About your implementation, running on chrome, it felt a bit slow and if I moved my mouse fast enough, it would not move the element. How exactly it is wonky on Firefox?

Comment: The move is very sluggish and the mouseup event handler seems not to be working after I release the mouse. Div still move with mouse..

Comment: You're binding to body, but the body's height is determined by its content, unless you define it to something else. Try setting a body background color and you'll see what I'm saying. This might be one of your issues... Also, as an experiment, bind `mousemove` and `mouseup` to your `$('html')` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! use $('html') will make Fireworks work! But why? It seems body will span the whole browser space.

Comment: Do you mean `Firefox`? :-) The reason is that `body` is a block element and it grows as large as its contents, unless you tell it otherwise (like `body { height: 100% }`).

Comment: haha, yeah, sorry! But the under my browser the body indeed occupy the whole screen even if I don't explicitly write "height:100%"... Wondering why.. [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kk7lmynmmxq023/Screen%20Shot%202014-06-17%20at%201.37.05%20PM.png)

Comment: True. I think I might have given a wrong tip. Setting the body background color on its own won't give you the right impression of how height your body is. Set `html { background-color: white; } body { background-color: blue; }` and you'll see it. Also try inspecting it with you devtools and you'll see how height it is.

Comment: Thanks, this is fabulous!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add height (100%) to body in css:

```
body{
   height:100%;    
}
```

Updated your Fiddle

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LXUuh/8/)